# How do I authenticate with the Buffer API (or similar) from AWS Lambda?

Tags: oauth, aws-lambda

I'm building a little lambda function to retrieve Twitter posts that I've made using Buffer (along with their # of retweets & likes, etc.)

I currently login to Buffer via Twitter OAuth. I can't quite see how this would from a Lambda function. Ideally I would just use the Buffer registered app's id/secret/token as environment variables in my lambda, but it doesn't appear to be that simple.

Any ideas? I'm using Serverless, and I see the [Serverless Authentication](https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication) package, but my understanding of OAuth is bottoming out.

Comment: what's wrong with authenticating to twitter per lambda, then _reusing_ that token for the life of the instance? (capped to the maximum lifetime of the token)

Comment: @TrentBartlem Do you mean authenticating outside of lambda? I think the tokens only last like 30 seconds or something. I need to run this in a recurring cron job.

Comment: Perhaps put stuff into the SSM parameter store, then other lambdas can use that to login (or have already-logged-in tokens available to them)